# VueJs trying to get the id and value of clicked element so I can post the data to the database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, request, vue-component

I am trying to make certain jobOffers visible and invisible with a toggleButton.
When the page is loaded a get request reads true or false out of the database to decide of the toggleButton is toggled or not.
I am trying to get the value and Id of the child that has been clicked so I can send a request to the database to let it know that it went from 'invisible' to 'visible' for example (next time the page is loaded).

I tried multiple ways but I don't think I understand how it works fully? So I have a parent page/component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <navigation-bar role="COMPANY"/>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="page-menu">
        <CompanyPageSelectorMenu/>
      </section>

      <section class="job-offers" v-if="jobOffers">
        <div class="scroll" id="scrollbar-styling" v-for="jobOffer of jobOffers" :key="jobOffer.id">
          <CompanyJobOfferList :functionBold="jobOffer.jobFunction" :amount-per-session="jobOffer.amountPerSession" :functionDescription="jobOffer.jobDescription" :isChecked="jobOffer.visible"/>
      </div>
      </section>


    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CompanyPageSelectorMenu from "../components/CompanyPageSelectorMenu.vue";
  import NavigationBar from "../components/NavigationBar";
  import CompanyJobOfferList from "../components/CompanyJobOfferList";
  import axios from 'axios';
  import {Utils} from "../assets/utils"

export default {
name: "CompanyJobOffer",
  components: {NavigationBar, CompanyPageSelectorMenu, CompanyJobOfferList},
  data () {
    return {
      jobOffers: [],
      errors: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    let userId = Utils.parseJwt(Utils.getCookie("JWT-token")).userId;

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/joboffers/` + userId, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${Utils.getCookie("JWT-token")}`
      }
    })
        .then(response => {
          this.jobOffers = response.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
  }
}
</script>
```

and in the parent it uses a component:

```
<CompanyJobOfferList :functionBold="jobOffer.jobFunction" :amount-per-session="jobOffer.amountPerSession" :functionDescription="jobOffer.jobDescription" :isChecked="jobOffer.visible"/>
```

the child component is the following:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <span class="function-text-bold"><b>{{ functionBold }}</b></span>
      <span class="function-text">{{ functionDescription }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <span class="amount-text">Aantal toegelaten studenten per sessie</span>
      <div class="click-amount">
        <button class="remove-hover"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z"/></svg></button>
        <span class="function-text">{{ amountPerSession }}</span>
        <button class="remove-hover"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z"/></svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>Stel je tijdslot in</button>
    <!-- Rounded switch -->
    <label class="switch">
      <!-- <input type="checkbox" v-model="this.isChecked" v-on:click="!this.isChecked">-->
      <!-- <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked"-->
        <input type="checkbox" v-if="isChecked" checked="isChecked">
       <input type="checkbox" v-else>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <hr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


//import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "CompanyJobOfferList",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: {
    functionBold: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    functionDescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    amountPerSession: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    isChecked: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How would I be able to get the Id of the clicked component? And if I know which component clicked I would need its current value? Do you make the post/put request in the child component or in the parent component. Why would you make it either in the parent or the child component? My first thought was to send the data to the parent because the parent makes multiple child components? I tried a variety of different options but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$emit`.
Pass an event and id to child component and call method on button click.
Parent component:

```js
<CompanyJobOfferList @buttonClicked="handleClick" :id="jobOffer.id">
```

Add method to parent component:

```js
handleClick(arg) {
  // do whatver using arg
}
```

Child component button

```js
<button @click="$emit('buttonClicked', id)"></button>
```

Child component props

```js
props: {
  id: {
    type: ?,
    required: true
  }
}
```